# New Identity? - Multiple Slit Diffraction

Tags: optics, double-slit-experiment, diffraction

To provide some context, I'm a high school student who has recently covered diffraction. For an assignment, I was tasked with exploring certain subtleties surrounding multiple slit diffraction (small angle approximation, far-field approximation, etc,), and how deriving relationships which consider these subtleties, and using them to solve for an unknown (i.e. measuring the wavelength of a laser), affect the accuracy of said unknowns. Now, I'm sure we are all familiar with the following:

[image]

Of course, the equation above outputs highly inaccurate values as $\theta_L$ increases. Such a discrepancy can be reduced by simply assuming that $r_1$ and $r_2$ are virtually parallel, and without accompanying this assumption with the small-angle assumption the following equation arises:

\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
d\sin{\left(\theta_D\right)}=\ \lambda\\\theta_{L\ }=arctan{\left(\frac{y}{L}\right)}\\\theta_D\approx\theta_{L\ }\\\therefore\ \lambda\ =\ d\sin{\left(arctan{\left(\frac{y}{L}\right)}\right)}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
Long story short, I was unsatisfied with this (since it still assumes that both rays are parallel), and out of frustration I eventually managed to derive the following:

[image]

[image]

What I would like to know if such an identity has been found, and published before, and if so, why hasn't it mentioned commonly in literature?

I can't seem to find anything of the sort.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you please say more clearly what identity you are asking about.

Comment: @M.Enns 
$\lambda\ =\ dsin{\left(arctan{\left(\frac{y+\frac{d}{2}}{L}\right)}\right)}$
and:
$\lambda=\left(n-1\right)dsin{\left(arctan{\left(\frac{y+\frac{\left(n-1\right)d}{2}}{L}\right)}\right)\ }\forall n\geq2$

Comment: You are thinking right. We can generalize it to n slits. For example diffraction gratings in the labs have many slits (not just 2). It is a standard topic and should be available in any textbook. I found this immediate [notes](https://www.classe.cornell.edu/~liepe/webpage/docs/Phys2208_lecture34.pdf).

Comment: @PRAJWALH.P. the equation for N-slit interference at the site you linked is much simpler than the one the OP is providing, they seem different.

Comment: @ Daddy Kropotkin That is because, OP is not happy with the assumption of $r_1,r_2$ being parallel (i.e L>>d). So he has tried to calculate explicitly. Otherwise its the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula assumes that $r_2-r_1=d*sin(\theta)$ but this is just a good  approximation! Draw a circle of radius r1 with midpoint P it will not go through D. So you formula is not wrong but as the other formulas only an approximation the better L>>d.
If you want the exakt distance r2-r1 you can do it by Pythagoras. All the approximations help to see what happens and were very useful before the age of calculators and computers. If you want exact results you can easily calculate with the exact formula.

If you take the line perpendicular to PE instead of PB your approximation will be better and you find the formula in literature.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer my question, however I have some inquiries regarding what you stated.
$r_2−r_1=d\sin\left(\theta\right)$ -> This represents the phase difference $r_1$ and $r_2$, I don't see how that's assuming anything. Yes, the circle you have mentioned will not intersect through D but I don't see how that's relevant. 
Also, what 'exact formula' are you referring to? You said that if I 'the line perpendicular to PE instead of PB' my 'approximation will be better', I'm assuming you mean I should consider $\angle PEC$ instead of $\angle PBF$ but that still assumes L >>d.

Comment: Oh no, ok I see what you mean.

Comment: The exact result is for example with Pythagoras for r1 and r2, r2-r1 gives not the phase difference but the way difference. And yes ∠ is what I mean